# How do I make a diagonal line in this code?

Tags: python, tkinter

The final product should look like this [image]

How do I make the triangle in the lower part of the image? So far I only got the 6 stripes. I'm using tkinter and random.

```
import tkinter
import random
import math
import time

canvas = tkinter.Canvas(width=600 ,height=400)
canvas.pack()
previerka = tkinter.Tk()
frame = tkinter.Frame(previerka)
frame.pack()

def shooting1():
    for a in range(8000):
        y = 0
        x = 0
        xr = random.randint(0,600)
        yp = random.randint(0,600)
        if yp <= 600:
            canvas.create_oval(x+xr,y+yp,x+xr,y+yp, outline="yellow", width=2)
        if 100 <= xr <= 300:
            canvas.create_oval(x+xr,y+yp,x+xr,y+yp, outline="black", width=2)
        if 200 <= xr <= 400:
            canvas.create_oval(x+xr,y+yp,x+xr,y+yp, outline="blue", width=2)
        if 300 <= xr <= 500:
            canvas.create_oval(x+xr,y+yp,x+xr,y+yp, outline="green", width=2)
        if 400 <= xr <= 600:
            canvas.create_oval(x+xr,y+yp,x+xr,y+yp, outline="white", width=2)
        if 500 <= xr <= 700:
            canvas.create_oval(x+xr,y+yp,x+xr,y+yp, outline="red", width=2)
button1=tkinter.Button(frame, text="shooting", fg="black", bg="white", command=shooting1)
button1.pack()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you realize this but you are overlapping all the color dots (try changing the width of any oval to 3 or 4 and you will realize this). You need to calculate if x and y values are compatible according to that line `y = 2x/3` (for a computer y-axis is inverted, so `y = 400 - 2x/3`). Then and only then you will draw on that canvas. Here is an example.

```
import tkinter
import random

previerka = tkinter.Tk()
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(previerka, width=600, height=400)
canvas.pack()
frame = tkinter.Frame(previerka)
frame.pack()

def shooting1():
    y = 0
    x = 0
    i = 0
    r  =("%02x"%random.randint(0,255))
    g = ("%02x"%random.randint(0,255))
    b = ("%02x"%random.randint(0,255))
    rand_color="#"+r+g+b

    for _ in range(20000):
        xr = random.randint(0,600)
        yp = random.randint(0,400)
        if yp<=400-2*xr//3:
            if xr < 100:
                canvas.create_oval(x+xr,y+yp,x+xr,y+yp, outline="yellow", width=2)
            elif xr < 200:
                canvas.create_oval(x+xr,y+yp,x+xr,y+yp, outline="black", width=2)
            elif xr < 300:
                canvas.create_oval(x+xr,y+yp,x+xr,y+yp, outline="blue", width=2)
            elif xr < 400:
                canvas.create_oval(x+xr,y+yp,x+xr,y+yp, outline="green", width=2)
            elif xr < 500:
                canvas.create_oval(x+xr,y+yp,x+xr,y+yp, outline="white", width=2)
            elif xr <= 600:
                canvas.create_oval(x+xr,y+yp,x+xr,y+yp, outline="red", width=2)
        else:
            canvas.create_oval(x+xr,y+yp,x+xr,y+yp, outline=rand_color, width=2)

button1=tkinter.Button(frame, text="shooting", fg="black", bg="white", command=shooting1)
button1.pack()
previerka.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, yes i do realize that im overlapping the color dots.

Comment: the triangle is also supposed to have a random color, not sure how to do that in your code

Comment: @patressxd What do you mean by a "random" color? If it is just one color, how can it be random. Kindly elaborate a bit.

Comment: any color for now (for example pink). I mean its supposed to be selected randomly every time you press the button but I'll figure that out later.

Comment: @patressxd Note that, I have increased the number of iterations, so that it is clearly visible. You can of course change that.